# Trying to Generate a Random password

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-ise

I have the below powershell script where I am creating a new user & trying to set its required properties. Problem I am facing is, I am not able to set a random password by creating a "Get-Password" function. Please have a look.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
[xml]$dataSource = Get-Content C:\Names1.xml

$name = Read-Host 'Please enter the table name : '

$user_logon = $dataSource.names.$name | ? { $_.Rule_Label -eq 'Regular service account (user logon)'}

$display_name = $dataSource.names.$name | ? { $_.Rule_Label -eq 'Regular service account (display name)'}

$pre_windows = $dataSource.names.$name | ? { $_.Rule_Label -eq 'Regular service account (pre-Windows 2000)'}

Function GET-Temppassword() { 
Param(
[int]$length=10, 
[string[]]$sourcedata 
)

For ($loop=1; $loop –le $length; $loop++) { 
        $TempPassword+=($sourcedata | GET-RANDOM)
        }

return $TempPassword
}

switch ($name) 
{ 
    DevTable{foreach($dataRecord in $dataSource) 
    {
    try     
    {
    $cn=$user_logon.Output_Value
    $sAMAccountName=$user_logon.Output_Value
    $givenName=$user_logon.Output_Value
    $sn=$user_logon.Output_Value 
    $displayName=$display_name.Output_Value 
    $userPrincipalName=$sAMAccountName + “@test.com”;

    $alphabet=$NULL;For ($a=65;$a –le 90;$a++) {$alphabet+=,[char][byte]$a }
    GET-Temppassword –length 10 –sourcedata $alphabet

    New-ADUser $cn -SamAccountName $sAMAccountName -GivenName $givenName -Surname $sn -DisplayName $displayName -UserPrincipalName $userPrincipalName -accountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $alphabet -Force) -PasswordNeverExpires $true -Path "OU=Service,OU=Accounts,DC=xyz,DC=com"  

    set-aduser $cn -replace @{comment="xxyyzz"}
    set-aduser $cn -replace @{"account"=1}      

    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity xyz -Member $cn
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity abc -Member $cn

    write-host "New DevTable ADUser has been created!!!";
    }

    catch [Exception]
    {

        write-host "Error - Requested AD Service Account is already present...Please check & confirm " -foreground "red"
    }
    }   
    break;
    }

    default {"The table could not be determined!!!"}    

}   

[System.GC]::Collect()
```

Also, I wanted to know if this is the most suitable way to set a random password.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "not able to set a random password"? Are you not getting a password, or does the password that you're generating fail to meet your password restrictions (length, type of characters, etc.)? What, if any, error messages are you getting?

Comment: My user is not getting created in this case when I try to add the AccountPassword attribute.

Comment: If you post a line or two in content of $dataSource it might help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$alphabet=$NULL;For ($a=65;$a –le 90;$a++) {$alphabet+=,[char][byte]$a }
GET-Temppassword –length 10 –sourcedata $alphabet

New-ADUser $cn -SamAccountName $sAMAccountName -GivenName $givenName -Surname $sn -DisplayName $displayName -UserPrincipalName $userPrincipalName -accountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $alphabet -Force) -PasswordNeverExpires $true -Path "OU=Service,OU=Accounts,DC=rjfdev,DC=com"
```

You aren't capturing the value returned from `Get-Temppassword`. You're passing `$alphabet` as the new password for the user account. Try this (untested):

```
$alphabet=$NULL;For ($a=65;$a –le 90;$a++) {$alphabet+=,[char][byte]$a }
$TempPassword = GET-Temppassword –length 10 –sourcedata $alphabet

New-ADUser $cn -SamAccountName $sAMAccountName -GivenName $givenName -Surname $sn -DisplayName $displayName -UserPrincipalName $userPrincipalName -accountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $TempPassword -Force) -PasswordNeverExpires $true -Path "OU=Service,OU=Accounts,DC=rjfdev,DC=com"
```

Comment: I am afraid, but the random password did not get set even after making the above change.

Comment: @alroc is correct but he added a typo to his fix. In his fix, change `$TempPassword-Force` to `$TempPassword -Force` and try it again. I've edited the answer but it needs to be accepted.

Comment: @charleswj81, your edit was rejected by 3 out of 4 reviewers for the reason of "This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.". Which is really a shame, because your edit was completely valid, and is in fact a "substantive improvement addressing multiple (well, the only) issues" - without that space, the code **was** wrong. I wish there was a way to review the reviewers.